# How can I sort files/directories in Azure File Storage by creation/modification time?

Tags: azure-storage

Is there any way to get or sort the Azure files/directories by creating time? I am using Azure Storage Browser to browse the storage.

Comment: This might be worth an upvote; https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/35263225-sort-files-by-date

Comment: The feedback link does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no.

The created date is not even tracked -- only the last modified date. You could track the created date using metadata, but this still would not allow sorting via that field. Files are sorted alphabetically, so if you used the created date as part of the name that might allow what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer for the same purpose. Please see image, I am able to sort by dates and do more with this.
[image]

Comment: That's Modified, not Create Date